# Small section of PHP/mysql code dies. Not sure why

Tags: php, mysql

I rarely do programming. I only know enough to be dangerous as they say and I simply assemble bits of code to get what I want. My code below seems to die at the `$sql` query statement. It never returns any data. It should show the 13 records that are present, but it says there is none to return. I'm guessing this is some kind of syntax error?

```
<?php
$host = 'myipaddress';
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$db = 'mydatabase';

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());

// Create connection
//$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: ");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE pid > '5'";
$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["pid"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: this `$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)` doesn't do what you think it does. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php - same for `$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);` Again, RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: *Ah, that too Sam* - @JayBlanchard amongst other things.

Comment: I have no idea why your question was downvoted, we all have to start learning somewhere. My advice here. Research before you try to code, mysqli and pdo are the preferred methods for database access now as they are more secure. Learning both at once may make your life difficult, so choose one and stick with it until you have it covered then learn the other if you feel it will benefit you. Ive corrected the down vote as i dont think it was justified.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the `mysql_` API right up until you try to fetch rows here, where you're using `mysqli_`. That will not work.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["pid"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
}
```

[Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

**EDIT**: Your connection (*Good Eyes Ralph!*) string will not work because `mysql_connect()` doesn't accept the database as part of the connection. You must use the additional function [`mysql_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) to choose your database.

In addition, it is not necessary to specify the connection link in [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) but if you do it should be the *second* argument:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in place of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, because your previous functions are based on `mysql_*`, not `mysqli_*`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["pid"]. " - Name: " . $row["title"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit wrong with your code.

`mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)`

`mysql_connect()` uses 3 parameters, the 4th doesn't do what you think it does.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

You need to use `mysql_select_db()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Then,

`$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);`

The connection comes second in `mysql_`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Then you're mixing a MySQLi function `mysqli_fetch_assoc` which doesn't intermix with the `mysql_` library.

- Read: [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

So, just use the full MySQLi library

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

or PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Along with a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

Check for the real errors, should your query fail:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

As you can see, I did not provide you with a full rewrite, as I feel that in *"Teaching a person how to fish..."*, will feed them for life, rather than *"Throwing them a fish..."*, and only feed them for a day (wink).